# Two users and one VirtualBox VM

Tags: macos, virtualbox, users

I have one VirtualBox VM (Windows) that I would like to share asynchronously with multiple users on an OS X Machine. How should this system be set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they will be using the VM at separate times, put all the VM files in some shared location. (I usually use `/vm`.) The easy way to do that is to set VirtualBox's preferences to look there as the default VM location.

If you want them to be able to use it simultaneously, that's less trivial, so mention if you do.

Comment: I recommend `/Users/Shared/` for path. It's a [user space directory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/WhereToPutFiles.html) designed to be both [readable and writeable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CFPrefTopScores/Introduction/Intro.html) by all users on a Mac, and is the only location that exists by default to behave this way.